# TableView issue with reuse system and design programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with my cells where I remove/insert to my `tableView`, I delete and insert my cells like that :

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
user.lobbySurvey.remove(at: 0)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Insert:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
user.lobbySurvey.insert(surveyEnded, at: rowToInsert)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToInsert, section: 0)], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

`lobbySurvey` is the data array of the TableView.
Problem is the cell I add keep the design of the first cell that I delete previously.

I think this issue is because I check if the card is draw or not. If not checked: the view of the card is added each time the cell is reuse.
this is how I check if the cell is draw or not :

```
func drawSurveyEnded(){
    if(cardIsDraw == false){
        surveyEnded.draw(cardView: self.cardView)
        surveyEnded.delegate = self
        self.addCardShadow()
        cardIsDraw = true
    }
}
```

The function is called many times cause to the reuse system of iOS. So I think my problem come from here.

Why my cell in my tableView keep the design of the previous cell that I deleted?

**Other code :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Celll") as! CardCell
for survey in user.lobbySurvey{
    let index = user.lobbySurvey.index(where: {
        //get the current index is nedeed else the cells reuse lazy
        $0 === survey
    })
    if indexPath.row == index{
        var surveyState : UserSurvey.state
        surveyState = survey.state
        switch surveyState{
        case .selectSurvey:
            cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .selectSurvey)
        case .goSurvey:
            cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .goSurvey(picture: survey.picture))
        case .surveyEnded:
            cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .surveyEnded(picture: survey.picture))
        case .surveyWork:
            print("survey in progress to vote")
        case .surveyWaiting:
            cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .surveyWaiting(selfSurveyId: survey.id, timeLeft: survey.timeLeft, picture: survey.picture))
        case .buyStack:
            cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .buyStack(supView : self.view))
        }
    }
}

cell.delegate = self
cell.delegateCard = self
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
tableView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
return cell
}
```

Draw card is a simple switch of the state of the survey where called the good function to create the card like this one I posted before : `drawSurveyEnded`

Comment: it' coming from cache. That's why it showing your previous cell data.

Comment: @JayPatel Yes ok, this is what i think. So any possibilities to remove the "cache" for this cell ?

Comment: Can you show your cellForRowAt method code for more understanding.

Comment: @JayPatel I've add the code to my question.

Comment: you didn't specify cell for particular index. So use this tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Celll", for: indexPath) instead of tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Celll").

Comment: can you also post the `drawCard` function?

Comment: @BrunoPaulino I've edited my answer !

Comment: @JayPatel I've change my code to your code and this change nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

In your CardCell you have to implement prepareForReuse and clean the cell's view from there. So when cells are recycled, they are cleaned from the previous views that were drawn.

Comment: I test this but this is the same as `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay...)` This superimposed the view despite I iterate cardView to delete all subviews ...

Comment: Then I suggest, in your cellForRowAt, to just use user.lobbySurvey[indexPath.row] instead of nesting loops (.index(where:) inside the for) and see if it works, maybe cell.drawCard() is getting called multiple times because of that. Or call break after the switch completes.

Comment: Ok I test and post the issue here in 10 hours approximately.

Comment: So, this don't work. I think I go to create 6 different cells and appropriate his own design

Comment: @El-Burritos make sure you are removing subviews and sublayers

Comment: I solved my problem with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075831/method-to-create-tableview-with-dynamic-cell-and-programmatically-design?noredirect=1#comment93049944_53075831). I add 6 different cells for each design and edit the cell if needed in cellForRowAt

Answer (score 0):

You should implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Update the cell here
}
```

This way you can make sure the cell gets updated whenever it is ready to be shown.
Remember the UIKit framework keeps a cache for the cells, so it can just reuse them.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, yes but when I update my cell in this function the cell is draw a second time and all my view are superimposed.